# How can I run a performance and diagnostics session on a Surface RT machine?

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-debugging, performance-testing, windows-rt

I am trying to launch a remote performance and diagnostics session on my Surface RT machine in Visual Studio Express 2013 by selecting Debug -> Performance and Diagnostics.  However, I get the following message:

> Diagnostics session failed to start.
>
> Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named '192.168.11.43:4018 (< device name >)'.  Connection request was rejected by the remote debugger. Ensure that the remote debugger is running in 'Windows Authentication' mode.

OK, fair enough, so I change the remote debugger to Windows Authentication mode, but no matter what I do I can't authenticate because my PC and tablet are on different domains (that is the way it seems anyway).  The tablet is running Windows RT, of course, so it is impossible to change the domain.  I have tried to start the remote debugger from the command line using the `-u` switch with the username and domain from my PC but that was no good either since the tablet can't authenticate it.  I also tried to join the tablet's domain on my PC using the script from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/528268) but I don't get a successful return value (the return value is 5).

Most of the blogs I have come across say "just save yourself the trouble and switch to 'No Authentication' mode" which is what I did in the first place, but the diagnostics session refuses to run this way.  What hoops do I have to jump through to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can get this to work on an RT. Our team has Pros for exactly this reason. Not being able to join a domain is the killer. :(